# OpenID Connect with .Net Core 3 and React

Tags: reactjs, openid-connect, asp.net-core-3.0

We are building a web application using React as the frontend and .Net Core 3 as the backend. We need to use OpenID Connect authentication with a couple of providers.

As far as I have seen, I found a lot of examples using only react with different components or packages, and some examples with .net core with the AddOpenIdConnect extension to the authenticationbuilder at the Startup, but I can't find a way to combine those two.

Maybe creating my own loginpage in react and call an api in my backend that does all the authorization flow? But the ideal solution would be using the openidconnect middleware in .net core, so we can use the authorize tags, or do some things like loading some profile configuration at a succesfull login...

Any hints on where I can find documentation on this matter or a bit of explanation about how to approach this? I'm a bit desperate here.

Thanks.

Comment: what did you end up doing? in similar situation

Answer (score 1):

You may check IdentityServer (Nuget Package IdentityServer4) it implements OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0. and there is a ready made templates, you can just type `dotnet new react -au Individual` and you will get an SPA with .net core Identity for authenticating and storing users ,combined with IdentityServer to use OPenID Connect.

[IdentityServer docs](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/intro/big_picture.html)

[Create an app with API authorization support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1)